# What is the best way to integrate bootstrap theme on VueJS

Tags: webpack, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-cli, bootstrap-themes

What do you think is the best way to embed a bootstrap theme on VueJs?
Assuming I do not want to use bootstrap-vue to not rewrite all the template?
How and where to include the bootstrap.min.css file, as well as all font files that depend on it?

I init the project with vue-cli with wepack-simple template

Comment: Have you tried including `bootstrap.css` into you `index.html`?  Why does that not work for you?  You have said why you don't want to use bootstrap-vue, but I would expect you to say why one of the most common ways of including CSS into a document `<link>` won't work.

Comment: he has asked a valid question

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Bootstrap CSS file like any other CSS file in the `head` of `index.html` should work (cf [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

No need to include the fonts, the CSS will get them.